# How to list no foreignkey related field

Tags: django

From the title how to list all the fields which no foreign key associated with it.

```
models.py
class Books(models.Model):
    pdf = CharField
    album = ForeignKey(Album,, null=True, blank=True))
```

Now i want to list all the pdf files which no associated or linked with  album_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
pdfs_without_album = Book.objects.filter(album__exact=None).values_list('pdf', flat=True)
```

This will fetch all Book objects from database that doesn't have FK on album field set. And then will create list of attribute pdf from all matching objects.